# Right join not joining?

Tags: mysql, sql

So... my right join isn't working. That sounds really vague, and all things considered, it probably is actually working. However, for the life of me, I can't figure out what's going on! For the sake of simplicity, here's my query. I understand that it is a little localized, but it's pretty straightforward.

```
SELECT a.answer, a.element_id, e.element_type, e.question, e.description
FROM cal_form_answers a
RIGHT JOIN cal_form_elements e
    USING(element_id)
INNER JOIN cal_forms f
    USING(form_id)
WHERE f.org_id = ?
    AND e.form_id = ?
    AND
    (
        a.member_id = ?
        OR a.member_id IS NULL
    )
GROUP BY a.element_id
ORDER BY e.order
```

The problem is, this is only returning `cal_form_elements` that have a corresponding `cal_form_answer`. However, because I am using a right join, shouldn't this also include elements that do *not* have a corresponding answer? Or am I misunderstanding right joins entirely?

Thank you!

**EDIT**: Here's an example fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8d99/1

Comment: Can you post a small sample of rows from each table, or better even, setup a demonstration at http://sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: Why do the results not include elements 4 and 5? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8d99/1

Comment: Ah, because you have multiple values for `element_id = 5`, others with a different `member_id`. So there's never a case where `element_id = 5` and `member_id IS NULL` because there are instances where `member_id = 30001`. If I get a chance, I'll try to work out an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `cal_form_answers` table includes multiple possible relationships with `cal_form_elements`, your attempt at `OR member_id IS NULL` couldn't succeed if other `member_id <> 30000` existed in the table.

Instead, you can move the `member_id` value condition *into* the joining condition.  You also had a `GROUP BY`, which isn't really appropriate since you have no aggregate functions (`MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),SUM()`, etct).  MySQL permits it, but the behavior can be somewhat indeterminate.

I used a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `RIGHT JOIN` if for no reason than I find them more intuitive. The result is the same.

```
SELECT 
  /* Changed some of the table sources for common columns here... */
  a.answer,
  e.element_id,
  e.element_type,
  e.question,
  e.description
FROM
  cal_form_elements e
  /* Perform a LEFT JOIN on element_id and require member_id = 30000 */
  /* if this isn't met, cal_form_elements will still return */
  LEFT JOIN cal_form_answers a ON e.element_id = a.element_id AND a.member_id = 30000
  INNER JOIN cal_forms f ON e.form_id = f.form_id
WHERE 
  f.org_id = 'church3562'
  AND e.form_id = 1
/* Inappropriate GROUP BY removed */
ORDER BY e.`order`
```

[Here's the fixed up sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8d99/11), and here is the [`RIGHT JOIN` version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8d99/12) since that's what you started with.

Of course you can substitute your placeholders.

```
SELECT 
  a.answer,
  e.element_id,
  e.element_type,
  e.question,
  e.description
FROM
  cal_form_elements e
  LEFT JOIN cal_form_answers a ON e.element_id = a.element_id AND a.member_id = ?
  INNER JOIN cal_forms f ON e.form_id = f.form_id
WHERE 
  f.org_id = ?
  AND e.form_id = ?
ORDER BY e.`order`
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The `GROUP BY` needs to be present as well for my purposes (sometimes, there may be multiple `answer`s for one `element`, but I only need one result) but I got it all working. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful using the group by that way in MySQL. It isn't portable and can sometimes produce confusing results.

Comment: If you know a better way, I'd love to hear it! I was experimenting with `COALESCE()` a bit, but I didn't quite get it working.

Comment: @NathanaelShermett If you modify the sqlfiddle to insert a rowset that demonstrates where you'll get multiples, I can work out how to do it without the group by, but if you're okay with the group by as it is and it works for you, stick with it. It's just something to be aware of - we see lots of questions here from people moving to a different RDBMS and not understanding why `GROUP BY` no longer works as they've come to expect or doesn't work at all.